# Text File to Dictionary with multiple columns

Tags: python, dictionary, key, rows

I have a text file with the following content in it

last name, first name, email, some arbitrary id number, and a phone number.

Hill, Jonah, jonahhill@outlook.com, 015666, 123-456-7890

Reynolds, Ryan, rrdp@yahoo.com, 1081254, 789-456-1230

Baccarin,Morena, bmdp@yahoo.com, 1011340, 159-753-4561

...

I want to make a dictionary for each row, but have keys to name such as last name, firstname etc.

here's the code I'm trying

```
d = {}

with open("oldFile.txt") as f:

d = dict(x.rstrip().split(None, 1) for x in f)

print d
```

I get something like this with all the content in the file in one whole dictionary

{'"hil"': '"jonah" "jonahhill@outlook" "015666" "123-456-7890"'...}

The results I'm looking for is

First person:

{lastname: "hill" , firstname: "Jonah", email: "jonahhill@outlook.com...}

Second person:

{Reynolds, Ryan, rrdp@yahoo.com, 1081254, 789-456-1230}

Third person:
...

I want keys to print them out individual such as

in file1 print out first person and I get

First person:

{lastname: "hill" , firstname: "Jonah", email: "jonahhill@outlook.com...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `zip`.

```py
keys = ['lastname', 'firstname', 'email', 'id', 'phone']
dicts = []
with open("oldFile.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        # Split each line.
        line = line.strip().split()
        # Create dict for each row.
        d = dict(zip(keys, line))
        # Print the row dict
        print d
        # Store for future use
        dicts.append(d)
```

The dictionaries for each row are available in the list `dicts`.

Comment: currently you can use `print dicts[index]` to print a dictionary by using the row's line index

Comment: I get the order of the keys mixed up when I print them out ... why is that? I get lastname, phone, email, firstname, id in that order

Comment: That's because a `dictionary` is unordered. Try to use `OrderedDict` to get ordered keys. An `OrderedDict` object remembers the order entries were added.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get the job done:

```
keys = ['lastname', 'firstname', 'email', 'id', 'phone']
file = open('oldFile.txt', 'r')
results = []
while True:
    line = file.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    else:
        content = line.split(', ')
        dict = {}
        index = 0
        for value in content:
            if value != '\n':
                pair = {keys[index]: value}
                dict.update(pair)
                index += 1
        if dict != {}:                          # Prevent empty lines from appending to results
            results.append(dict)

for dict in results:
    print dict
```